# Relative URL not working in System.Web.UI.UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, resolve

```
public class foo : System.Web.UI.Control
{
    public foo()
    {
      var a = new HyperLink(){ Text="Test", NavigateUrl="~/abc.aspx"};
      this.Controls.Add(a);
    }
}
```

The above code works properly, and when added to a page will successfully identify the tilde / ~ symbol and convert the url into a relative url.

However, when I change the derivation of the class to `System.Web.UI.WebControl` it does absolutely nothing, and leaves the tilde / ~ intact.

I had a look at `System.Web.UI.Control` which implements the `IUrlResolutionService` interface, but still can't seem to get `System.Web.UI.WebControl` to resolve urls.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the System.Web.VirtualPathUtility class:

```
public foo()
{
  var a = new HyperLink()
      { 
          Text="Test", 
          NavigateUrl=VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/abc.aspx")
      };
  this.Controls.Add(a);
}
```

Comment: I would like the class to resolve the urls and also learn why they dont.

Comment: not sure but may be WebControl doesn't support this relative mapping...i'll check it out

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this to get root and them map my path:

[HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.applicationvirtualpath.aspx) + "/mypath/mypage.aspx"